# React how to add an extra array in set of array list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in React which renders options in checkbox form.
I want to add another option by appending it to this list.

My render function

```
typeof this.state.vendorsOccasionTypesList != 'undefined'
  ? this.state.vendorsOccasionTypesList.map(function(row, i) {
      if (
        row.ifActive == '1' &&
        row.cityId == that.props.sessionData.CityId
      ) {
        var mainName = row.name;
        var id = row.contractorVendorsTypeId;
        var mainName1 = mainName.replace('BookEventZ', '');
        options.push({ value: id, label: mainName1 });
        options.concat({ value: 57, label: 'mainName1' });
      }
    }, this)
  : null;
```

Comment: This is too much of a dogs breakfast to work with. You use `that` and `options` without declaring/ initialising them. Also use `===` where you can. Why is `mainName1` in and out of quotes (as it's a variable probably should be unquoted) ? etc etc

Comment: `this.state.vendorsOccasionTypesList.concat([anotherOption])`?